# Get numbers after a certain string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a a string containing this text...

> BEGIN Fin    Bal -461.000  Day 4  END
>
> BEGIN Fin    Bal 88861.000  Day 2  END
>
> BEGIN Fin    Bal 456461.000  Day 1  END
>
> BEGIN Fin    Bal -44561.000  Day 0  END

I need to extract the value

> -461.000

Including if its negative or not.

I have been using this...

```
static string ExtractNumbers(string expr)
{
    //removes all text from string
    return string.Join(null, System.Text.RegularExpressions
                 .Regex.Split(expr, "[^\\d]"));
}
```

Problem is this removes the negative symbol and also keeps the 4 from the day value.

Is there any way to get the numeric value after the word Bal efficiently? Excluding any text after the wanted value?

Thanks, Paul.

Comment: Does the string always start with `BEGIN Fin Bal`

Comment: One example is not enough for a regular expression to be constructed. Please give several more examples (for instance, does this always start with `BEGIN Fin Bal `? Is the value always starting with `-`?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a regex that will filter out only the floating point numbers. Try this: `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$` EDIT: or you might try this: `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

Comment: Sorry added some more string examples to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a LINQ solution which grabs the first number:

```
string str = "BEGIN Fin Bal -461.000 Day 4 END";
decimal d;
string n = str.Split(' ').Where(s => decimal.TryParse(s, out d)).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(n == null ? "(none)" : decimal.Parse(n).ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help that's perfect! I think LINQ  would be more efficient if I'm not wrong? As there are a few hundred lines to read! Thanks, Paul.

Comment: I am not sure which is more efficient (trivial to test), but when you are talking a few hundred lines, the difference should be inconsequential. In general, go for clarity and maintenance ease over performance unless you have no choice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it might help you

```
(?<=Bal\s)-?\d+\.\d+
```

See **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Explanation

```
Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=Bal\s)»
   Match the characters “Bal” literally «Bal»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s»
Match the character “-” literally «-?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex:

```
^([^\d]*?)(-?[0-9.]+).*$
```

Inside the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match()`.

Answer (score 0):

For a regex, try the following, and get the first capture:

```
/Bal (-?\d*?\.?\d*?)/
```

But if your text is always in the format "blah blah Bal NUMBER Day blah blah", how about:

```
str.Split(new string[] {"Bal ", " Day"})[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

RedFilter's answer is nice and compact, but LINQ is not a very efficient method here: it will go through "BEGIN", "Fin" and "Bal" before it gets to your number. Note also that RedFilter's method uses both a TryParse *and* a Parse for the same operation (I understand this is a side effect of how LINQ works, but it's extra overhead in my mind). If it's always going to be the fourth item in your string, you may try something similar to:

```
 string val = "BEGIN Fin Bal -461.000 Day 4 END"; 
 float FinBal;
 bool success = float.TryParse(val.Split(' ')[3], NumberStyles.Float, new NumberFormatInfo(), out FinBal);
 if (success)
 {
     Console.WriteLine( "{0:F3}",FinBal);
 }
```